# DIV horizontally centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

look at my blog's index page http://lowcoupling.com/
it is a tumblr blog based on Twitter Bootstrap
I cant see how to horizontally center the google plus one button in the second column of the row defined for each post. The result is that, as you can see, it appears to be more distant from the post title.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [I said on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799335/1947677),
you need to add the `text-center` class to  the middle column and the problem is solved.

```
<div style="height:70px;" class="col-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
```

Comment: fine! I didn't get there was a class for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to align the google button with the post title?

If yes, then you can try by applying the following css code:

.col-2{padding:12px 15px;}

Hope this works for you.